# If I have a list of numbered questions, how can I align my questions to the right of the number?

Tags: line-numbering

I'm editing a paper with a bunch of questions numbered from 1 to 10.  In the example that my professor gave me, he had it formatted so that the number of the question would be listed, and then the question itself would be aligned with it's own margin next to the number. I know in Microsoft Word, for example, it aligns itself automatically, but I don't know how to do that in TeXStudio.

Is there some command that I don't know about?

Comment: have you tried `enumerate` environment?

Answer (score 4):

A simple `enumerate` environment seems to be what you need (or do you want some other alignment for the labels?):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Question 1.
\item Question 2.
\item Question 3.
\item Question 4.
\item Question 5.
\item Question 6.
\item Question 7.
\item Question 8.
\item Question 9.
\item Question 10.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]